# SynchronizationContext and DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: c#, dispatcher, synchronizationcontext

I am having a case where an exception thrown in UI thread doesn't get catched in the calling thread.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace SynchronisationContextAndExceptionWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        }


        private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                _synchronizationContext.Send(
                    x =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            DoSomethingOnUiThreadThatThrowsException();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Catched Exception in thread that threw it.");
                            throw;
                        }
                    }, null);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Catched Exception in thread that calles Send-Method.");
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void DoSomethingOnUiThreadThatThrowsException()
        {
            throw new Exception("Any Exception...");
        }
    }
}
```

First I thought that cannot possible (all documentation I found said that I can catch exceptions there). 
After some reasearch I found the problem: My application uses an UnhandledExceptionHandler. That handles the `DispatcherUnhandledException`-Event. I am showing some information to the user and set `e.Handled = true;`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace SynchronisationContextAndExceptionWPF
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
        }

        private static void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(
            object sender,
            DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Catched Exception in UnhandledExceptionHandler.");

            // This line makes the difference:
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So the question: why is the `DispatcherUnhandledException`-Event raised even if I handle it?
How would you solve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of controls, you can generate a new class which remenbers the special exception variable. So you only need to change the initialization of your _synchronizationContext (hopefully only once at your base class of your controls).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MySynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _synchronizationContext = new MySynchronizationContext(SynchronizationContext.Current);

    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _synchronizationContext.Send(
                x =>
                {
                    DoSomethingOnUiThreadThatThrowsException();
                }, null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Catched Exception in thread that calles Send-Method.");
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static void DoSomethingOnUiThreadThatThrowsException()
    {
        throw new Exception("Any Exception...");
    }
}

class MySynchronizationContext
{
    SynchronizationContext innerContext;

    public MySynchronizationContext(SynchronizationContext ctx)
    {
        innerContext = ctx;
    }

    public virtual void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        Exception threadException = null;

        try
        {
            innerContext.Send(_ =>
            {
                try
                {
                    d.Invoke(state);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    threadException = exception;
                }
            }, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        if (threadException != null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Synchronization error", threadException);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me! It maybe is not the general solution for all but makes me happy right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your lambda expression you can set an Exception variable and check this variable later at the calling thread. If it was set, then throw exception at calling thread.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception threadException = null;

        try
        {
            _synchronizationContext.Send(
                x =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DoSomethingOnUiThreadThatThrowsException();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Catched Exception in thread that threw it.");
                        threadException = ex;
                        //throw; --> don't throw exception here; otherwise you will get DispatcherUnhandledException twice.
                    }
                }, null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Catched Exception in thread that calles Send-Method.");
            throw;
        }

        if(threadException != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Catched Exception in thread that calles Send-Method.");
            throw threadException; //throw you previously catched exception here.
        }
    }
```

Kind Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Sure this would work... but means that I have to remember to call it this way every time... additionally: if I have a modularized software where I have controls that work this way (and don't know about the UnhandledExceptionHandler) they would not work as expected...